# Как решить пример с прогрессией?

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно решить `P=2/3*4/5*6/7...2N/2N+1`

в данном примере я так понимаю у меня одна переменная - N.
Как формулы записываются на Java?

Comment: как обычные выражения

Comment: Артём, а вам циклы уже объясняли?

Answer (score 1):

В Java, как и в других *императивных* языках, вы должны не описать желаемый результат, а точно специфицировать процесс вычислений, по шагам.

Для того, чтобы подсчитать такую сумму, традиционно используют *циклы*. Например, можно сделать так, чтобы на первой итерации цикла подсчиталось `2/3`, на второй `2/3*4/5`, на третьей `2/3*4/5*6/7` и т. д.

Вам понадобится, понятно, переменная (подумайте, какого типа!), в которой у вас будет накапливаться текущее вычисленное значение куска формулы. После выполнения (скольких?) итераций в вашей переменной окажется нужное значение.

Многоточие Java не понимает, это нотация для людей. Ваше задание как бы и состоит в том, чтобы из этого многоточия извлечь алгоритм подсчёта.

---

Поскольку это явно учебное задание, код не даю.